# macos: How would I find the top fastest growing files and directory

Tags: macos, storage

How would I find the top fastest growing files and directory subtree to see what's gobbled
up all the space on macos?

Answer (score 1):

Easy and free is the **How to free up storage space on your Mac** guide

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996

Make a screen shot of the two top images once a day for three days running or once a week, you can see growth and then know where to focus your cleanup efforts. DaisyDisk is nice, too but start for free is my advice.

[image: Storage]

[image: Reduce Clutter]

If you like command line tools, [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) is the ticket and https://brew.sh is a popular option to get it and other similar tools installed and patched over time.

Comment: ok, downloaded ncdu. you'd laugh at du output: /dev/disk1s5    250G    11G    26G    31% apparently 11+26 equals 250 in cupertino math

Comment: Indeed @AntonTropashko with APFS and snapshots and COW this part of “Learn More” is carrying a ton of water - “ Disk Utility and other apps might show storage categories such as Not Mounted, VM, Recovery, Other Volumes, Free, or Purgeable. Don't rely on these categories to understand how to free up storage space or how much storage space is available for your data.”

Comment: I don't. I have most of the space wasted in "Other". Which is not of as much use as I hoped though it turned out 4 or 5 binary frameworks in Pods weight 100MB+ each. And I have 3-4 clones of the repo with Pods checked in.